# How does XGBClassifier identify positive labels for scale_pos_weight parameter?

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm currently setting up a model using `XGBClassifier()` for a binary classification task in an unbalanced dataset (positive:negative = 1:20). Positive label is encoded as `1`, negative label is encoded as `0`. When trying to optimize the parameter `scale_pos_weight` via  `GridSearchCV(scoring=roc_auc)` with otherwise default parameters, my assumption was that values >1 and roughly around 20 would perform better, as a typical value per documentation is `sum(negative instances) / sum(positive instances)`. However, the gridsearch always ends up prefering the lowest value in the grid as low as `scale_pos_weight=0.1`.

My guess is that the model considers 0 as positive class. Is there any way to confirm/change that? The documentation I found offers no explanation on how `XGBClassifier()` identifies the positive label.

As a sidenote, performing the same gridsearch using `catboost.CatBoostClassifier()` with default settings results in higher optimal values for `scale_pos_weight` as expected.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can try to compare your results with using `xgboost.DMatrix` which would have weights applied accordingly to the fraction of labels (in your case: weight of the negative label should be `1/(20+1) = 0.0476`). if the results are the same for `scale_pos_weight` being a small number, maybe XGBoost assumes that positive number should be encoded as `0`, as you suggested yourself.

Comment: The most prominent effect of changing class weights is to skew the predicted probabilities, which won't affect the AUC much.  So using the scorer `roc_auc` may be causing the grid search to more-or-less randomly selecting a winner.  First, check the `cv_results_` to see how the AUCs vary over different `scale_pos_weights`.  I'd also suggest a diagnostic that checks the output probabilities: plot a histogram of the predicted probabilities for a few different values of `scale_pos_weight` and see if they move in the expected direction.